# Displaying Node object content in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I simply display the Node object using below code, the content is displayed correctly.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(Node);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to do the same same with a reference to the Node object from its parent (Object.Node), but 'undefined' is the result in this case. Can you please let me know the reason for such behavior?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(Object.Node);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Node` is a property of Window, not of Object. `Object` is not global either.

Answer (score 0):

The Node object represents a single node in the document tree.

A node can be an element node, an attribute node, a text node, or any other of the node types.

Notice that while all objects inherits the Node properties / methods for dealing with parents and children, not all objects can have parents or children. For example, Text nodes may not have children, and adding children to such nodes results in a DOM error. So, we do not have `Object.Node` but there is `Node` defined.